# Is there any way to dismiss alarms from the vehicle touchscreen via Android Auto?

Tags: alarm, android-auto

I often set alarms in Android with the default clock application ([com.google.android.deskclock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock)) and sometimes an alarm goes off when I've connected my phone to the car using Android Auto and am using the phone through the car's touchscreen.

Unfortunately, there's no way to dismiss the alarm from the car touch screen, the only way to dismiss the alarm is from the phone's screen. This is a problem because then I have to pull off to the side of the road and take out my phone to safely dismiss the alarm.

So far the only workarounds I know of are to disable all alarms, or less drastically to change the "Silence after" setting from 10 minutes to 1 minute, which is undesirable for other reasons.

This issue has been present in all the versions of Android I've used since at least 2019, but for what it's worth I'm currently using Android version 13 on a Pixel 6 Pro. I'm using Android Auto version 10.2.633224-release and Clock version 7.5 (551400242). The car is a 2017 Ford CMAX Energi which I believe uses the SYNC 3 interface.